# save some information from form that is images and some other information

Tags: django, forms

models.py

```
    class seller(models.Model):
        username     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        bedroom_no   = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        kitchen_img  = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',height_field=970 , width_field=400)
        swimming_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',height_field=970 , width_field=400)
        phone        = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        email        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        price        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        floor        = models.CharField(max_length=4)
        squre        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        gerden_img   = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',height_field=970 , width_field=400)
        pro_img      = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',height_field=970 , width_field=400)
        state        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        city         = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        full_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
def register_seller(request):
    rm = request.POST.get('remember','off')
    if rm == 'on':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            userName = request.POST['userName']
            state = request.POST['state']
            city = request.POST['city']
            full_address = request.POST['fulladdress']
            out = request.FILES['out']
            bedroom_no  = request.POST['bedroom_no']
            kithen_img = request.FILES['kitchen']
            swimming_img  = request.FILES['swimming']
            phone = request.POST['phone']
            email = request.POST['email']
            price = request.POST['price']
            floor = request.POST['floor']
            squre = request.POST['squre']
            garden_img = request.FILES['garden']
            each = seller_detail(state=state,city=city,full_address=full_address,pro_img=out,username=userName,bedroom_no=bedroom_no,kitchen_img=kithen_img,swimming_img=swimming_img,phone=phone,email=email,price=price,floor=floor,squre=squre,gerden_img=garden_img)
            each.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request,'all/seller_input.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'all/seller_input.html',{'remember':'Please checkout the button'})
```

but a problem is occur "getattr(): attribute name must be string" 
now what i do

Comment: you just posting `input into a function`, you need to describe what's the function about and the code for it

Comment: rm = request.POST.get('remember','off')
    if rm == 'on':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            userName = request.POST['userName']
            state = request.POST['state']
            city = request.POST['city']
            full_address = request.POST['fulladdress']
            out = request.FILES['out']
            bedroom_no  = request.POST['bedroom_no']
            kithen_img = request.FILES['kitchen']

Comment: swimming_img  = request.FILES['swimming']
            phone = request.POST['phone']
            email = request.POST['email']
            price = request.POST['price']
            floor = request.POST['floor']
            squre = request.POST['squre']
            garden_img = request.FILES['garden']
            each = seller_detail(state=state,city=city,full_address=full_address,pro_img=out,username=userName,bedroom_no=bedroom_no,kitchen_img=kithen_img,swimming_img=swimming_img,phone=phone,email=email,price=price,floor=floor,squre=squre,gerden_img=garden_img)
            each.save()

Comment: @KrishanKumawat you need to add this in your question

Comment: yes you can add those code to your question by clicking the edit button in your question, also seem like you saving the wrong type of data to the model

Comment: can you post your full view ?

Comment: view is uploaded in the above comment

Comment: not in comment it should be in your question

Comment: i added views.py